# Cordova ios WKWebView first touchstart event not firing when keyboard is up

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, wkwebview

I just upgraded my cordova app from UIWebView to WKWebView and I noticed when I set input on a contenteditable (which brings up the keyboard) and then click on a button outside of the contenteditable, the first `touchstart` event does not fire (or to be precise, it fires but only on `window`, not the button). The next touchstart works as expected.

I need the touchstart to bring up a list of contacts (and not close the keyboard).

Anyone knows what's up with that, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was actually caused by me not shrinking the viewport (might be related to https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard/issues/32 ?). There's a setting for that in cordova.